# Angular 2 Firebase or AngularFire Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I am encountering an error when trying to hook David Easts TODO Angular2 demo up with Firebase.

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

The repo can be found here: https://github.com/davideast/ng2do

All I have done differently is: import bind, AngularFire and FirebaseArray:

```
import {bind} from 'angular2/di';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseArray} from 'firebase/AngularFire';
```

And register componentServices:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'todo-app',
  componentServices: [
    AngularFire,
    bind(Firebase).toValue(new Firebase('https://webapi.firebaseio-demo.com/test'))
  ]
})
```

This results in an error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1050. I'm looking at it today.